# Laravel ... Automatically execute a script after few hours

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible with laravel to logout a user automatically after few hours, say 10, even of the browser is closed and user doesn't log-out manually.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set session timeout in Laravel 4.2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071747/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-laravel-4-2)

Comment: This look slike it's already been answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071747/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-laravel-4-2

Comment: It seems the accepted answer here answers a slightly different question, which is how to modify the session timeout in Laravel. If that was the question you intended, it might be worth modifying the title, so that it does not appear your next question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In app/config/session.php look for this code:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Lifetime
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
| to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
| to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
|
*/

'lifetime' => 120,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Set 'lifetime' to the amount of time you want the session to be active for, in minutes. e.g. if you want 10 hours set it to 600.