# Is it possible to run a script after few hours or at specific time automatically with Laravel even if the browser window is closed?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible to run a script after few hours or at specific time automatically with Laravel even if the browser window is closed?

I am trying to build a web based system where employee checks in when they arrive at office and the office time ends at 6:00PM at evening. So if the user do not checks out manually, the system should run a script automatically and checks the user out at 6PM.

Also there is option for employee to take a break for 20 max minutes, so if the user does not end the break after 20 mins, the system run a script to check the user out.

Comment: Yes, with a cron job, or a queue task

Comment: Agree with @LeventeNagy

Comment: Any specific resource??

Comment: Laravel docs queue: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener, Cron job: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel ... Automatically execute a script after few hours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28603972/laravel-automatically-execute-a-script-after-few-hours)

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of your previous question?

Comment: I think that wasn't specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a cron job for your script.