# Laravel 4.2 Auth never expire

Tags: session, authentication, laravel-4

I set session lifetime to 1 minute, why the session never end?

After ***10 minutes*** of inactivity , i refresh my browser (chrome or firefox)
and my user still logged in.

This is my app/config/session.php

```
'lifetime' => 1,

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

Comment: Did you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26121822/1692333) ?

Comment: The session expiry settings in the php.ini file might be conflicting with the Laravel settings.