# How to extend session lifetime in Laravel 7.X

Tags: laravel, session, lifetime

I'm newbie in laravel.
How I can set up session lifetime in Laravel 7.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set session timeout in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071747/how-to-set-session-timeout-in-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

Set it in .env file.

SESSION_LIFETIME=minutes?

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```