# Is it worth using Session + Cookie in Laravel 9?

Tags: laravel, session, cookies

I'm building a Laravel 9 app that relies a lot on saved data for the user. Currently, I'm using Sessions only to retrieve this data from the user later on (anywhere from 1-600 minutes after the first visit).

Would it be wiser to use Session AND Cookies together, or would it be obsolete? I'm guessing if we lose the session data somehow, then we would use the cookie data as well? Obviously, first looking at the Session data, if it doesn't exist, then check the Cookie data.

Are there any other viable mechanisms to save user data and retrieve it at a slightly later time?

Comment: Both storages is for temporary use only. Session for some minutes (if you add more minutes will have performance issues on scale) and cookies until user deleted it (or enter in incognito mode) with storage limitation per browser. That's why we use databases, maybe no sql for performances. 

You didn't give much information why you don't need database to store those changes, i guess you don't have login users, but i think with sessions you have more flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can update `'lifetime'` in `config/session.php`.

Have a look at this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26231287/9882603

Comment: It's not really about the timing. I know it could be updated. My question focuses on whether it is worth having both options instead of just relying on Session - even if it's time is extended.